# why docker inspect return a list?

Tags: docker

When i use `docker inspect <image_id>`, i find this command return a list, so it is has mulitple item? and why design that?

I found document on https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/, but not explain.

```bash
docker inspect tomcat
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:9f35737a8466774032dfeed82dc20670db1c097d6fdbc576ab92d85b3f6f9902",
        "RepoTags": [
            "tomcat:latest"
        ]
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: because it is possible to set multiple ids? `docker inspect <image_id1> <image_id2>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes , so that you can pass multiple options after command like multiple image id or different format for different images.